# Ember JS The value that #each loops over must be an Array

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Fairly new to ember js and I've encountered this error.

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed '[Saab,Volvo,BMW]' (wrapped in (generated favorites controller))
```

On my `route/favorites.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // the model is an Array of all of the posts
    // fetched from this url

      var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
    return cars;
  }
});
```

That's the only line from my route/favorite.js

and on my app/router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('favorites');
});

export default Router;
```

and my favorites.hbs

```
<h1>{{appName}}</h1>

<ul>
{{#each controller as |item|}}
  <li>{{item}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li>{{item}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

---

**Background:** Ember.ArrayController is deprecated in the current version of emberjs.  The code you used would work if you had an Ember.ArrayController defined but this is now discouraged. Instead, I am guessing an Ember.Controller is created for you automatically as you have not shown one. Therefore, you should be using the `model` property on the controller and loop over that.

Comment: Thanks! I was following the guide in the documentation looks like they did not mention it. a other resources for learning ember?

Comment: @user962206 yet, the guides are not up to date.  The core team is organising a documentation team right now for ember 2.0.